# Как убрать дубликаты вывода строки в консоль в решении задачи

Tags: java

Данную задачу:

> Напишите программу, которая получает символы, введенные с клавиатуры, до
>   тех пор, пока не встретится точка. Предусмотрите в программе счетчик пробелов.
>   Сведения о количестве пробелов должны выводиться в конце программы.

Решил так:

```
public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException {
    char choice, exit;
    int space;
    exit = '.';
    space = 0;
    for (; ; ) {

        System.out.println("Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:");

        choice = (char) System.in.read(); // Получили символ от пользователя.

        if (choice == ' ') space += 1; // Добавили пробел если он был нажат.
        else if (choice == '.') System.out.print("Programm stopped by exit. " +
                "Space pressed " + space + " times."); /* Закончили на точке и показали пробелы. */

    }
}
```

Вывод получается такой.

> Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:
>   Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:
>   Programm stopped by exit. Space pressed 2 times.Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:

Почему строки повторяются и как убрать дубликаты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы выводите "Press any key..." на **каждой** итерации цикла. Поэтому сколько символов было введено - столько раз сообщение и будет выведено
2. При получении `.` вы не останавливаете цикл, так что программа будет работать бесконечно

Первую проблему можно решить вынесением сообщения за цикл, а вторую - добавлением `break`-а при нахождении `.`:

```
char choice, exit;
int space;
exit = '.';
space = 0;
System.out.println("Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:");
for (; ; ) {
    choice = (char) System.in.read(); // Получили символ от пользователя.
    if (choice == ' ')
    {
        space += 1; // Добавили пробел если он был нажат.
    }
    else if (choice == '.')
    {
        System.out.print("Programm stopped by exit. " +
            "Space pressed " + space + " times."); /* Закончили на точке и показали пробелы. */
        break;
    }
}
```

---

А ещё в коде можно немного прибраться:

```
int spacesCount = 0;
boolean gotExitSymbol = false;
System.out.println("Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:");
while (!gotExitSymbol)
{
    char symbol = (char)System.in.read(); // Получили символ от пользователя.
    if (symbol == ' ')
    {
        spacesCount++; // Добавили пробел если он был нажат.
    } 
    else if (symbol == '.')
    {
        gotExitSymbol = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("Program stopped by exit. " + "Space pressed " + spacesCount + " times."); /* Закончили на точке и показали пробелы. */
```

Убрал лишние переменные, другие переименовал, использовал `++` вместо `+= 1`, а `while (true)` (он же `for (; ; )`) заменил на `while` с флагом (очень не люблю `while (true)` за то как он выглядит)

---

Или несколько короче при использовании в `while` сложного условия вместо флага:

```
int spacesCount = 0;
System.out.println("Press any key please. Press '.' for exit:");
char symbol;
while ((symbol = (char)System.in.read()) != '.')
{
    if (symbol == ' ')
        spacesCount++; // Добавили пробел если он был нажат.
}
System.out.println("Program stopped by exit. " + "Space pressed " + spacesCount + " times."); /* Закончили на точке и показали пробелы. */
```

Comment: Сердечная благодарность за такой прекрасный, подробный ответ! Все работает замечательно, только первый вариант вашего кода "вылетает" после двух вариантов. Сможете подсказать что нужно подправить? (в первом)

Comment: @MR на здоровье. Мм, а _"вылетает" после двух вариантов_ - это как? Падает с exception-ом на каких-то входных данных?